# Why is echoing a quoted date bash command adding a space?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-interface

I am encountering unexpected behavior I don't yet understand. In bash on OSX I get different outputs for the two following commands:

```
echo $(date)
Tue May 2 00:24:02 EDT 2017

echo "$(date)"
Tue May  2 00:24:10 EDT 2017
```

The quoted version adds a space before the day number.

What's going on?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) for a gallery of effects caused by not quoting when using `echo` (command expansion and variable expansion are affected in the same way)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `date` command prints an extra space before the day-of-month if the day-of-month is a single digit.

Here's your first command:

```
echo $(date)
```

Since you didn't put double-quotes around `$(date)`, the shell performs word-splitting on the output of `date`, and passes each word as a separate argument to `echo`. In word-splitting, the shell considers two consecutive spaces to mean the same thing as a single space. So the shell “eats” the extra space emitted by `date`.

Here's your second version:

```
echo "$(date)"
```

Since you put double-quotes around `$(date)`, the shell does **not** perform word-splitting on the output of `date`. It passes the entire output of `date`, except for trailing newlines, as a **single** argument to `echo`. So the shell preserves the extra space that was output by `date`.

Comment: If not obvious from this description, `date` outputs two spaces and it's the unquoted version that strips a space, not the quoted version that adds one.

Comment: Thank you @thatotherguy. I have incorporated your feedback into my answer.

Comment: Thank you all for clear answers! You all explained it well in different but useful ways. This is a gotcha that got me on a project I'm on where I was grepping for a string with the extra space. I'm glad to understand this gotcha before it got me on something more serious!

Answer (score 3):

With `echo "$(date)"` you are passing a single argument to `echo`, and this is simply echoed *verbatim*. Without the quotes you are passing a a number of arguments, separated by white space, and each of these is then echoed with a single space between each argument, which effectively converts any multiple space separators into a single space.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what is exactly `date`'s output

```
$ date | xxd
0000000: 5475 6520 2032 204d 6179 2032 3031 3720  Tue  2 May 2017 
0000010: 3030 3a34 353a 3134 2045 4454 0a         00:45:14 EDT.
```

you can see 2 spaces

Comment: Great to know this one! I was actually trying to achieve this output when I was trying to troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The output of $(date) is  `Tue May  2 00:24:10 EDT 2017` with two spaces. Under `bash` and `echo` happens the same as with:

```
echo "x  y"
```

vs

```
echo x  y
```

The first version prints both spaces, the second just one space, because bash is splitting the arguments along whitespaces (`\w+`) and `echo` prints each argument with only one space as separator.